# Cast super class instance returned bya super class method to a subclass instance

Tags: java, inheritance

Consider:

```
public class Super
{
    Integer state = 0;

    Super f()
    {
        Super x = new Super();
        x.state = this.state + 1;
        return x;
    }
}

public class Sub extends Super
{
    Sub f()
    {
        return (Sub) super.f();
    }
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Sub s = new Sub();
        Sub t = s.f();
    }
}
```

This results in a crash:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Super cannot be cast to Sub
    at Sub.f(Sub.java:5)
    at Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

And yet, an instance of `Sub` is not in a smallest feature distinct from that of `Super`.

In a more realistic example, `Sub` would have exactly the same properties as `Super` *(which is
what makes me believe they can be safely cast both ways)*, but redefine some of its methods.

Is it possible to make this code work, without duplicating the definition of `f`?

Comment: From the _Java Language Specification_: [Narrowing Reference Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.6)

Comment: @Abra I am not sure what to make of it. Can you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's address the first part of the question :

> Is it possible to make this code work

In it's current state, the code cannot work because this is against the language specification as defined in *[Section 5.5.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.3)* of the *Java Language Specification* which states that :

> If T is a class type, then R must be either the same class (§4.3.4) as
>   T or a subclass of T, or a run-time exception is thrown

In the example provided in the question, (`return (Sub) super.f();` ), `T` is `Sub` and `R` is `Super`.

Let's now address the second part of the question :

> without duplicating the definition of f

One way to achieve this is to move the code that is common between `super` and `Sub` to a separate method :

```
public class Super {
    Integer state = 0;

    Super f() {
        Super x = new Super();
        incrementState(x);
        return x;
    }

    protected void incrementState(Super x) {
        x.state = this.state + 1;
    }
}

public class Sub extends Super {
    Sub f() {
        Sub s = new Sub();
        incrementState(s);
        return s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but your `f` operation should be **protected** inside class hierarchy.

```
static class Super implements Cloneable {
    int state = 0;

    // inspection
    public int getState() {
        return state;
    }

    // default behavior
    public void doSomething() {
        state += 1;
    }

    // unsafe, should be protected
    public <S extends Super> S f() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        // unchecked cast !!!
        S s = (S) this.clone();
        s.doSomething();
        return s;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }
}

static class Sub extends Super {
    // override behavior
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        super.doSomething();
        super.doSomething();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Sub s = new Sub();
    System.out.printf("%d => %d%n", s.getState(), s.f().getState());
}
```

With output:

```
0 => 2
```

Here, `f` return not `Super` but any `S` extending `Super`, now `f` will be closed under the group operations (each superclass operations). But must be **protected** since that cast is unchecked at compile time. Eg.

```
Sub s = new Sub();
Sub t = s.f();  // ok
Sub2 u = s.f(); // java.lang.ClassCastException !!!!
```

That is why `f` operation should be protected and not publicly exposed.

Comment: Nice, but I am not happy with this solution because of the exception that I now have to thread through every user of `f`.

Comment: you can avoid `CloneNotSupportedException` wrapping into a runtime exception (has nothing to do with the solution); you can write `try { ... } catch(CloneNotSupportedException e) { throw new IllegalStateException(e); }`.

Answer (score 1):

So the short answer is that yes, you can downcast. Provided that the actual object type at runtime is the target type you are down-casting too.

When your example runs `return (Sub) super.f();` it'll fail with a `java.lang.ClassCastException` as in this instance the actual object is not a `Sub`, it is a `Super`. You can see this by modifying your method a bit as follows:

```
Sub f() {
    Super sup = super.f();
    if(sup instanceof  Sub) {
        System.out.println("Instance of Sub");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not an instance of Sub, it is a : " +  sup.getClass());
    }
    return (Sub) sup;
}
```

The reason here is because in `Super f()` your instantiating a pure `Super` object and returning it, hence the actual object type is `Super` and since a `Super`is not a `Sub` so we cannot cast it to a `Sub`.

Here is an example:

```
public class Animal {

  private String type;
  private int age;

  public Animal(String type, int age) {
    this.type = type;
    this.age = age;
  }

  public int getAge() {
    return age;
  }

}

public class Cat extends Animal {
  public Cat(String type, int age) {
    super(type, age);
  }
}
public class Dog extends Animal {
  public Dog(String type, int age) {
    super(type, age);
  }
}

public class Vet {

  public static void printHumanYears(Animal animal) {
    if(animal instanceof Dog) {
        Dog dog = (Dog) animal;
        System.out.println("Dogs age : " + dog.getAge() * 7);
    } else if(animal instanceof Cat) {
        Cat cat = (Cat) animal;
        System.out.println("Cat age : " + cat.getAge() * 5);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not sure how to calculate age for a " + animal.getClass());
    }
  }

  public static void main (String [] args) {
    Dog dog = new Dog("Collie", 10);
    Cat cat = new Cat("Tabby", 20);
    Animal animal = new Animal("Animal", 20);
    printHumanYears(dog);
    printHumanYears(cat);
    printHumanYears(animal);
  }
```

}

When the method `printHumanYears(Animal animal)` is invoked, it is passed an `Animal` Object, we then check what this `Animal` object is an instance of and then downcast accordingly. The reason we would not get a `ClassCastException` is because the target object (either `Dog` or `Cat`) was create at run time. When we pass an `Animal` it can't downcast to either a `Dog` or `Cat` because it's neither of these when it was initially instantiated.

Good to remember:

- Casting does not change the actual object type.
- Casting only changes the reference type.
- Upcasting is always safe and never fails.
- Downcasting is not safe and can throw a `ClassCastException`, so always a good idea to use `instanceof` to check the the target type is what you are trying to cast too.

Comment: Nice, but this does not address the obvious consideration that _in actuality_ the shape of an instance of `Sub` and that of `Super` in memory are the same. In other words, I perfectly know that formally `super` is not a subtype of `this` _(duh, it is a supertype)_, but I also know that in actuality they are _the same_, and I want to use this latter knowledge to tell Java to do the cast.

Comment: Well, no they not the same objects in memory, because you are creating an new `super` when you call `Super x = new Super();`. As far as Java is concerned, the moment you instantiate this new object it is a completely separate and independent object of type `Super`

Comment: What I meant is that they are different locations in memory, but the same layout in memory.

Comment: But that's the thing. They not the same object types. You could completely hack your super class and instantiate the object to be the same based on whats calling it in the stack ... `Super f() {
        Super x = null;
        StackTraceElement[] cause = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        if(cause[2].getClassName().endsWith("Sub")) {
            x = new Sub();
        }
        if(x != null) {
            x.state = this.state + 1;
        }
        return x;
    }` .. but this solution is obviously not reusable.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. If two classes define exactly the same properties, and in fact one is a trivial subclass of the other, are they not equivalent with respect to memory layout?

Comment: Nope. They different objects in memory. Java is OK with up-casting (i.e a `Sub` is always a `Super`, because it extends it), but the same does not apply to down-casting as a `Super` isn't necessary a `Sub`.

Comment: Can you explain to me how they are different?